# duda sobre BasicPlayer

Tags: java

¿Cómo puedo visualizar el tiempo?

```
BasicPlayer bp=new BasicPlayer();
 String ruta="/musica/cancion.mp3";
 try {
     bp.open(getClass().getResource(ruta));
     bp.play();

    } catch (BasicPlayerException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(repro.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Lo que hice es colocar las canciones en un package y de ahí poner su ruta pero, **¿cómo puedo colocar el tiempo de una canción?**, alguien por favor me podría aclarar mi duda.gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: http://pablocarballude.blogspot.com/2007/11/reproducir-msica-mp3-ogg-wav-en-java.html Esto te puede servir

Comment: Hola ,es que ya lo intente de esa forma pero no logro hacer que me muestre ,de hecho tengo un error al crear basicPlayer.addBasicPlayerListener(this);.                    De hecho tengo agregadas al rededor de 12 librerías todas agregadas, todas sobre la gestión de música pero me marca error en eso.

Comment: Ya agregué la s

Comment: De igual forma probé con esto                                               
 float progressUpdate = (float) (bytesread * 1.0f / bytesLength * 1.0f);
 int progressNow = (int) (bytesLength * progressUpdate);
 // Descomentando la siguiente línea se mosrtaría el progreso
 // System.out.println(" -> " + progressNow);                                 pero solo me muestra cero una sola vez y no vuelve a mandar más datos o en otros casos "null"